# Strange behaviour on HTML inputs on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, safari

I have an interface of four numeric inputs for pin entry. As an input is populated the next is selected to give focus.

html:

```
    <div class="pinInputs">
    <div class="pinInputsWrapper">
        <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
            <input name="pinInput1" 
                   id="pinInput1" 
                   tabindex="1" 
                   maxlength="1" 
                   pattern="[0-9]" 
                   autofocus="true" 
                   data-autofocus="true" 
                   type="tel" />
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
            <input name="pinInput2" 
                   id="pinInput2" 
                   tabindex="2" 
                   maxlength="1" 
                   pattern="[0-9]"
                   type="tel" />
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
            <input name="pinInput3" 
                   id="pinInput3" 
                   tabindex="3" 
                   maxlength="1" 
                   pattern="[0-9]" 
                   type="tel" />
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
            <input name="pinInput4" 
                   id="pinInput4" 
                   tabindex="4" 
                   maxlength="1" 
                   pattern="[0-9]" 
                   type="tel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .pinInputs {
    max-width: 16.4em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.pinInputsWrapper {
    height: 3.2em;
}
.columns {
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

input {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #024734;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

input:not(:focus){
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -mox-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security: disc;
    -o-text-security: disc;
    text-security: disc;
    color: #31953e;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    $("input").bind("input change", function(ev) {
        var index = parseInt(ev.srcElement.id.slice(-1));
        if (index < 4 && ev.srcElement.value) {
            $('#pinInput' + (index+1)).select();
        }
    });
```

I've created it in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ek7rhgsj/8/

To Reproduce the issue:
Populate the inputs with single digit numeric characters and then move back deleting the content as you go. When all inputs are empty re-populate. The disc is now pushed to the bottom of the input rather thhan being vertically aligned. This is only reproducable on mobile safari. I can see it on iphones running ios 8.1.1, ios 8.2 and 9. It's possibly there on other versions but these are all the test devices I have available at the moment. Has anyone seen similar before and if so is there a workaround?

Any ideas greatly appreciated
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution for this.

Given that I was able to produce this easily in jsfiddle I knew it wasn't anything to do with the js framework I was using (mithril) but rather a browser specific issue. Since safari runs a different engine to chrome I thought that the way the input boxes were being selected to change focus was the probable cause. I didn't dig into this very deeply but using the element.focus() method in place of select solved the issue for me and had no other cross browser issues. If anyone has an explanation that goes a bit deeper I'd love to hear it :)

Thanks,
C